# HTML table - image in the cell has wrong height

Tags: html, html-table

EDIT: apparently it doesn't work only in Chrome 58. I added screenshots as the snippet doesn't always reproduce the issue.

I have a "image-frame" table - 3x3 cells, where in every cell, except the middle one, is one image which is one part of the frame.

```
+----+-------+----+
| LT |   T   | RT |
+----+-------+----+
| L  |       | R  |
+----+-------+----+
| LB |   B   | RB |
+----+-------+----+
```

Images in the cells are stretched via style arguments height and width set to 100%.
But it somehow doesn't work as I expect. The image in T and B cells is much more higher than height set for the row.

```html
<div style="POSITION:relative;-webkit-margin-collapse:separate separate;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:800108;CURSOR:default;">
  &nbsp;
  <div style="width: 424px;height: 42px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="6">
        <col>
        <col width="6">
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr height="6">
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M/wHwAEBgIApD5fRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30px" style="height: 30px;">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPj/HwADBwIAMCbHYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="" style="height: 30px;"></td>
          <td height="30px" style="height: 30px;">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPj/HwADBwIAMCbHYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="6">
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M/wHwAEBgIApD5fRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot from Chrome 58:

[image]

If I will remove `width="100%"` from the images in the TOP and BOTTOM cells, then the height will get fixed, but, of course, image is now not properly stretched horizontally.

```html
<div style="POSITION:relative;-webkit-margin-collapse:separate separate;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:800108;CURSOR:default;">
  &nbsp;
  <div style="width: 424px;height: 42px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="6">
        <col>
        <col width="6">
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr height="6">
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M/wHwAEBgIApD5fRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30px" style="height: 30px;">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPj/HwADBwIAMCbHYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td class="" style="height: 30px;"></td>
          <td height="30px" style="height: 30px;">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPj/HwADBwIAMCbHYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="6">
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M/wHwAEBgIApD5fRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
          <td height="6px">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" style="display:block" border="0"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot from Chrome 58:

[image]

Can someone explain me why is the sizing broken and how to stretch the images properly?

Comment: This HTML code is generated by SmartGWT framework. I just want to understand why the above code doesn't work as it seems to be correct. Then I can point exactly where is the issue to SmartGWT guys and ask them to fix their generator.

Comment: Your image links are broken with 403s

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. In my browser was everything looking ok, I guess images were already cached. Anyway, I changed the code to use data image now.